# How to prevent a div element to be affected by the box-shadow of another div element?

Tags: html, css

I am interested in making a website where 2 div elements with different size to drop a shadow, but without being affected by the other's shadow.

I have tried to put the same z-index in both elements, but the last one has priority over the first one and its shadow overlaps it.

So, as the title says, how could it be done?

EDIT: I have read the [Two divs with shadows looks like one part. Is it possible in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625025/two-divs-with-shadows-looks-like-one-part-is-it-possible-in-css) post, but that do not solve my problem because I can not move the shadow any pixel.

[image: Photoshopped image of what I want to do]

Comment: One option would be to use the first option, then add another blue box at the same location as the first one, but without the shadow, and a higher z-index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two divs with shadows looks like one part. Is it possible in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625025/two-divs-with-shadows-looks-like-one-part-is-it-possible-in-css)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not move the shadow any pixel"?

Comment: I am using JavaScript to handle some dynamic shadows and this must be set like this, I mean, without offsetting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment made by @jcaron solve my problem:

> One option would be to use the first option, then add another blue box at the same location as the first one, but without the shadow, and a higher z-index.

Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You could just omit the left-side shadow of the green box, or sort of.

```
.div2 {
  background:#B1FA00;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 gray, 
       0 0 0 transparent, 8px 8px 15px gray;
}
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/b1483vuk/1/

Example with both divs in white:

https://jsfiddle.net/b1483vuk/2/

Comment: It seems really good, but if both div elements have the same color (white, for example), you can still see the shadow so it doesn't solve my problem, sorry

Comment: Hmmm.  I just updated my answer with a second jsfiddle where both divs are white.  Seems to work fine on my machine (Chrome).  I just had to adjust the offset of the shadow by two pixels to the right.

Comment: I am using Firefox, which uses bigger shadows than Chrome, that could be the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you move the box-shadow to a pseudo element for each box, you can position the pseudo element behind both boxes using z-index.

The css would look like:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

It may not work in your situation, but the following fiddle demonstrates this:

https://jsfiddle.net/adrianlynch/16r8bp5a/

Comment: This does not work in my situation. Any clues why? I have cards in a grid and want to prevent them from casting shadows on each other.

Comment: I solved it! If the z-index on the div itself (not the ::after element) is set to a number, then this doesn't work for some reason. So instead of setting set the z-index to 0, set it to `initial` or `auto`, then it works.

Comment: I think my issue also had to do with the `will-change` css attribute since it creates additional layers that change the way things are rendered

Comment: Another addendum to the comment from @NoahNuebling : if you still have the problem of the shadow not showing up check if the overflow property is set at least to initial!

Answer (score 1):

Cover it up with a `:before` as @0b10011 said:

```html
<style type="text/css">
#two {
    position:relative; /* Add relative positioning */
}
/* Add :before element to cover up shadow */
#two:before {
    background:white;
    display:block;
    content:".";
    font-size:0;
    width:4px; /* Width of Shadow */
    height:100px; /* Height of #one */
    position:absolute;
    left:-4px; /* 0 - Width of Shadow */
    top:0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: but where is the shadow-box?

Comment: put it in both div elements

Answer (score 0):

Try offsetting the shadow so you isolate the left side of the green rectangle at set its `z-index` to be superior.

Try something like this.

```
box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px 10px #888888;
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/danielsinger/pen/grvJGw

Comment: The post I referred explains how to do it offsetting the shadows, but I can not offset them. I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple easy solution just using z-index and overlaying a div over another.
you will notice a slight thickening of the shadow around the join between yellow and green, this is from the div shadows overlapping, and as far as I'm aware (which is not very far), this is unavoidable.

```css
.a1 {
        z-index:5;
        width:50px;
        height:100px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px black;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:20px;
        background-color:white;
      }
      .a11 {
        z-index:10;
        width:50px;
        height:100px;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:20px;
        background-color:yellow;
      }
      .a2 {
        z-index:8;
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px black;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
        left:70px;
        background-color:green;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class=a1></div>
    <div class=a11></div>
    <div class=a2></div>
  </body>
</html>
```