# CSS underline and letter-spacing

Tags: css, typography, underline, letter-spacing

In a website menu, I have implemented some wishes of my customer concerning typography in CSS. She needs a different tracking on the font, no problem. But, she wants the active link to be underlined. As I have not implemented the code to target the active link, I just underlined them all to see how it would look. The CSS is as follows:

```
.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.45em;
    line-height: 4.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Menu of the website with styled links]

The problem is that the letter spacing kind of messes up the underlining. I've drawn some <strike>vote magnets</strike> freehand circles to indicate the problem. The line starts nicely at the left side but is extended with the value of `letter-spacing` to the right.

Screenshot is from Firefox 25. [Jsfiddle to see for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/JWcGh/1).

I could solve this using borders and using margins instead of line height, but is this fixable otherwise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015263/css-text-underlining-too-long-when-letter-spacing-is-applied

Comment: @isherwood, oops didn't see that.

Comment: If you want a critique on your design. Dont do the underline, it looks hideous, do a hover with a background change. See example. http://jsfiddle.net/JWcGh/3/

Comment: @Cam the underline will show what page a visitor is currently on, I don't mind if it's used for that. I'm just doing what the customer wants :) I'll give her advice eventually if the end result is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS Text underlining too long when letter-spacing is applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015263/css-text-underlining-too-long-when-letter-spacing-is-applied)

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/JWcGh/2

```
.main-navigation a:after {
  /* absolute positioning keeps it within h1's relative positioned box, takes it out of the document flow and forces a block-style display */
  position: absolute;
  /* the same width as our letter-spacing property on the h1 element */
  width: 0.45em;
  /* we need to make sure our 'mask' is tall enough to hide the underline. For my own purpose 200% was enough, but you can play and see what suits you */
  height: 200%;
  /* set the background colour to the same as whatever the background colour is behind your element. I've used a red box here so you can see it on your page before you change the colour ;) */
  background-color: #fff;
  /* give the browser some text to render (if you're familiar with clearing floats like this, you should understand why this is important) */
  content: ".";
  /* hide the dynamic text you've just added off the screen somewhere */
  text-indent: -9999em;
  /* this is the magic part - pull the mask off the left and hide the underline beneath */
  margin-left: -.40em;
}
```

Comment: This is very creative :) also interesting to note, if it's used on italic text you need to adjust `margin-left` or it chops off part of the last letter.