# CSS letter-spacing together with line-through

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any css/js solution how to center line through the text while using `letter-spacing`? While single line text it is possible to accomplish centered `line-through` thanks to pseudo element `::before` or `::after`, but that's not possible on block elements like `<p>` or `<div>`.

```css
h2, p {
  letter-spacing: 1em;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  letter-spacing: .5em;
}
```

```html
<h2>Random text</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at nemore aperiri cum. Regione honestatis ei quo, ne eos aliquid mediocrem, ne viris quodsi epicuri vel. Ex dolorem atomorum dissentiunt nam, iudico minimum cotidieque eum et, has novum mnesarchum id. Libris blandit liberavisse mei in. Ius viris posidonium ei, ut quas viris albucius eum, mei eu indoctum reformidans. Et usu sumo invidunt, cu vix veri dolore propriae.</p>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015263/css-text-underlining-too-long-when-letter-spacing-is-applied

Comment: But are you really looking for a js solution too? To what extent? I mean any js solution would have to understand your layout better, for instance, is this fixed or could the breaks change with resize, dynamic element insertion, hover etc?

Comment: I accept js solution too.. div/p with line-through can contain other html like ul, a, i so in JS solution must be every text row wrapped in span/div and listening to the window.resize event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea where you can rely on background and [box-decoration-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) to create the line-through and you can easily adjust its size and position. You will basically remove one letter spacing from the total width.

It's important to note that the background need to be applied to an inline element:

```css
p {
  letter-spacing: .5em;
  text-align:center;
}

p span {
  background:    
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) /* Coloration */
    0 calc(50% + 0.2ex) /* position */
    /
    calc(100% - .5em) 1px  /* width height */
    no-repeat;
 -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone; 
}
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at nemore aperiri cum. Regione honestatis ei quo, ne eos aliquid mediocrem, ne viris quodsi epicuri vel. Ex dolorem atomorum dissentiunt nam, iudico minimum cotidieque eum et, has novum mnesarchum id. Libris blandit liberavisse mei in. Ius viris posidonium ei, ut quas viris albucius eum, mei eu indoctum reformidans. Et usu sumo invidunt, cu vix veri dolore propriae.</span></p>
```

Comment: no time to check what happens but on FF seems like antialiasing makes things fuzzy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG29A.png

Comment: @Kaiido yes because of the small value of height (0.1em) and since it's not the same font, the value will not be the same and we will have subpixel rendring issue I guess

Comment: @Kaiido I switched to px value, it's more safe ... we have to change it manually if we increase the font-size

Comment: So far best 'mindblowing' solution which works under every intelligent browser.. according to *caninuse* box-decoration-break is not available in Edge (IE).

Comment: Very nice (nitpicking: unprefixed rule should go after -webkit-prefixed)